# Not sure of the correct syntax for a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am working off some other code that I just got on this site and this is the first time I've worked with a stored procedure so I'm really not sure how the syntax is supposed to work. I'm working in Teradata SQL Assistant. The goal is basically to create a macro with these variables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE member_count(
        IN state CHAR(2),
        IN state_mbr CHAR(9))

--We have to tell it here that we will be returning a result set
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN

--Declare variables we will be using at the top
--One variable for the sql string
DECLARE my_sql VARCHAR(5000);

--And another for the cursor that we will open for the result set
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR my_statement;

--Now we build our dynamically generated sql statement
--we use two single quotes together to escape the quote character
--(essentially we want a single quote in the SQL statement so we must
--double it as it's already inside single quotes).
SET my_sql = 'Select
    ''' || state || ''' as state
,case when m.var1 not in ('PREM','MPP') then 'SF'
        when m.var1 in ('JG',) then 'FI'
        when m.var1 in ('STU') and (m.var2 is not null or m.var2 not in ('xxx')) then 'HIM'
              else 'Other' end as lob
    ,count(m.dw_mbr_key) as members
FROM database. || state_mbr
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;'

---Now we "prepare" the "statement" from our string
PREPARE my_statement FROM my_sql;

---and we open the cursor. We don't close it because we want it returned.
OPEN my_cursor;
END;

CALL member_count(NM, NM_MBR);
```

My issue is how do I deal with single quotes? Such as the case when statement, is that an issue and something different needs to be done about it?

It's hard because I get no results or error messages. Only something that says 'Import style parameters found in query'.

Comment: Escaping single quotes can look pretty nasty. Usually you just put them 4 times and fiddle. My preferred way is to concatenate with a function which returns the single quote character. For example in Oracle you can use CHR(10). In Teradata I think you can use the hex value '27'XC. I don't have a Teradata instance on my machine at the moment though so I can't test it out. But just look at the output of SELECT '27'XC || 'test' || '27XC'

Comment: I put it in exactly like that and it returned 'test27XC

Comment: I fiddle with the quotes a bit, this should give well-formed SQL 
'''Select
    ''' || state || ''' as state
,case when m.var1 not in (''PREM''' || ',''MPP''' || ' then ''SF''' || '
        when m.var1 in (''JG''' || ',) THEN ''FI''' || '
        when m.var1 in (''STU''' || ') and (m.var2 is not null or m.var2 not in (''xxx''' || ')) then ''HIM''' || '
              else ''Other''' || ' end as lob
    ,count(m.dw_mbr_key) as members
FROM database. || state_mbr
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
'

Comment: Oops. Actually use this if you want to go the hex function route -- SELECT '27'XC || 'test' || '27'XC .Just for debugging though, I'd create a volatile table like CREATE VOLATILE TABLE DEBUG_VT  ( sqlStatement VARCHAR(2000)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; Then in your proc have INSERT INTO DEBUG_VT VALUES (my_sql); So that you can run your dynamic statement just by itself to make sure it really doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As @Error_2646 already wrote fiddling with quoted strings in Dynamic SQL is 
hard. You should start with a working query without parameters

```
SELECT
   'NM' AS state
   ,CASE WHEN m.var1 NOT IN ('PREM','MPP') THEN 'SF'
         WHEN m.var1 IN ('JG') THEN 'FI'
         WHEN m.var1 IN ('STU') AND (m.var2 IS NOT NULL OR m.var2 NOT IN ('xxx')) THEN 'HIM'
         ELSE 'Other'
    END AS lob
   ,Count(m.dw_mbr_key) AS members
FROM db.NM_MBR AS m
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Then you search & replace all `'` with `''`

```
SELECT
   ''NM'' AS state
   ,CASE WHEN m.var1 NOT IN (''PREM'',''MPP'') THEN ''SF''
         WHEN m.var1 IN (''JG'') THEN ''FI''
         WHEN m.var1 IN (''STU'') AND (m.var2 IS NOT NULL OR m.var2 NOT IN (''xxx'')) THEN ''HIM''
         ELSE ''Other''
    END AS lob
   ,Count(m.dw_mbr_key) AS members
FROM db.NM_MBR AS m
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

And single quote the whole query

```
'SELECT
   ''NM'' AS state
   ,CASE WHEN m.var1 NOT IN (''PREM'',''MPP'') THEN ''SF''
         WHEN m.var1 IN (''JG'') THEN ''FI''
         WHEN m.var1 IN (''STU'') AND (m.var2 IS NOT NULL OR m.var2 NOT IN (''xxx'')) THEN ''HIM''
         ELSE ''Other''
    END AS lob
   ,Count(m.dw_mbr_key) AS members
FROM db.NM_MBR AS m
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;'
```

Finally you replace the parameters with `' || myparam || '`, here `''NM''`  & `NM_MBR`

```
'SELECT
   ' || NM || ' AS state
   ,CASE WHEN m.var1 NOT IN (''PREM'',''MPP'') THEN ''SF''
         WHEN m.var1 IN (''JG'') THEN ''FI''
         WHEN m.var1 IN (''STU'') AND (m.var2 IS NOT NULL OR m.var2 NOT IN (''xxx'')) THEN ''HIM''
         ELSE ''Other''
    END AS lob
   ,Count(m.dw_mbr_key) AS members
FROM db.' || NM_MBR || ' AS m
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;'
```

Now you got a valid SQL string to be used  in Dynamic SQL.

As there's still a lot of potential problems/errors I usually define some error handling and an out message which returns information about successful execution or faliures:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE member_count(
        IN state CHAR(2),
        IN state_mbr CHAR(9),
        OUT msg VARCHAR(1000))

--We have to tell it here that we will be returning a result set
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN   
   -- constants
   DECLARE CRLF CHAR(2) DEFAULT '0D0A'xc; -- to simplify adding linebreaks
   -- I usually got multiple constants, e.g. for debugging.

   --Declare variables we will be using at the top
   --One variable for the sql string
   DECLARE my_sql VARCHAR(5000);

   --And another for the cursor that we will open for the result set
   DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR my_statement;

   --Now we build our dynamically generated sql statement
   --we use two single quotes together to escape the quote character
   --(essentially we want a single quote in the SQL statement so we must
   --double it as it's already inside single quotes).
   SET my_sql =
'SELECT
   ' || state|| ' AS state
   ,CASE WHEN m.var1 NOT IN (''PREM'',''MPP'') THEN ''SF''
         WHEN m.var1 IN (''JG'') THEN ''FI''
         WHEN m.var1 IN (''STU'') AND (m.var2 IS NOT NULL OR m.var2 NOT IN (''xxx'')) THEN ''HIM''
         ELSE ''Other''
    END AS lob
   ,Count(m.dw_mbr_key) AS members
FROM db.' || state_mbr || ' AS m
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;'
   ;

   ---Now we "prepare" the "statement" from our string
   BEGIN
      -- adding a handler to catch error information
      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SqlException
      BEGIN -- there was an error during PREPARE or OPEN
         DECLARE errortext VARCHAR(1000);
         DECLARE Errorcode CHAR(5);
         GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1
             errortext = Message_Text,
             Errorcode = Returned_SqlState;

         SET msg = 'Failed: ' || Errorcode || ': ' || errortext
                   || CRLF || 'SQL Statement: ' 
                   || CRLF || my_sql;
      END;

      PREPARE my_statement FROM my_sql;

      ---and we open the cursor. We don't close it because we want it returned.
      OPEN my_cursor;

      -- only execute if there was no error
      SET msg = 'Finished: ' || Trim(Activity_Count) || ' rows returned';
   END;

END;
```

Now the SP compiles, but your original CALL will fail with a `[3810] Column/Parameter 'member_count.NM' does not exist.`. You must pass your parameters as Strings:

```
CALL member_count('NM', 'NM_MBR', msg);
```

This runs and returns this `msg`

```
Failed: 52004: Database 'db' does not exist.
SQL Statement: 
SELECT
   NM AS state
   ,CASE WHEN m.var1 NOT IN ('PREM','MPP') THEN 'SF'
         WHEN m.var1 IN ('JG') THEN 'FI'
         WHEN m.var1 IN ('STU') AND (m.var2 IS NOT NULL OR m.var2 NOT IN ('xxx')) THEN 'HIM'
         ELSE 'Other'
    END AS lob
   ,Count(m.dw_mbr_key) AS members
FROM db.NM_MBR    AS m
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Caution, the CALL didn't fail, it run successful, but the handler catched the error and there's no result set returned.

If the Select runs successfull there are two result sets returned, the first is the message `'Finished: xxx rows returned' and the second the actual result.